# Whats the difference in starting an android app in eclipse debugger and on device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

Can some one point out the difference in starting an android app within the eclipse debugger and normally from a device. I am building an app which uses wifi direct. When its run from debugger it works fine but when it is started from a device as we normally start any app some features/services are not working.

Whats the basic difference between the two?

Thanks

Comment: define "some features are not working"

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. it will be hard to describe the features as it could be asked as a separate question. Here I am more interested in knowing the difference between running in the two cases.

Comment: You have asked about the debugger, and then about features/services.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Just want to know the difference in running a app in a debugger and normally from a device.